# How to extend reset time during MCU software reset? (STM32F427)

Tags: stm32, hardware, reset, cortex-m

I am solving a problem with **the software reset of the STM32F427** microcontroller. Doing a software reset of the MCU is not a problem, it works great and the MCU boots up nicely.

During the software reset, the processor pulls its reset pin to zero. This reset pulse is **now** a **few milliseconds long**. I am working on how to make this reset signal longer. I would **need** it to be about **10ms long**.

Does anyone know if and how this signal could be extended by modifying the software? (some wait instructions at the very beginning of the run, modification in the options byte, change in the system initialization code)

*This is what the MCU pin reset signal looks like during a software reset.*
[image]

**Background of the problem:**
I have a finished hw that runs normally and sometimes it is necessary to do a sw reset (fw update, untreated error, etc.). This hw has a COMMON reset pin for MCU and another chip (hw reset pins of both chips are connected). An RC element is connected to this signal so that the sources have time to warm up before the MCU starts up. It's fine on a cold start, but the SW reset has a reset pulse too short for the second chip. This second chip will then remain in a strange (non-functional) state. Therefore, I would need to extend the reset signal.
The HW is finished, it can no longer be modified. The reset connection was a bad idea.

Comment: Changing the capacitor in the reset RC-chain is not possible too?

Comment: Thanks for you comment. The hardware is already in operation in many pieces, any hw modification is very complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `nRST` pin is low no software is executed as the processor is in the reset state.

The only way to keep the `nRST` low for a long time is to have an external circuit to detect when `nRST` is pulled down and keep it for the required 10ms.

> The HW is finished, it can no longer be modified. The reset connection
> was a bad idea.

I am afraid you have to patch your hardware (you see it very often in production boards when errors are found too late)

Answer (score 1):

Datasheet, page 141:

[image]

I don't see any software mechanism to affect it. There is just one thing you can try - reduce clock speed before performing reset? And I mean to the ground, as low as you can go, maybe LSI (which will mean switching PLL parameters, APB/AHB dividers, internal power regulator, flash wait states, maybe something else too). There is a "generated reset pulse duration" in the table, and it doesn't have an upper bound. Maybe it will extend software reset time, if you do it while at low freqs. But as soon as reset happens, there is a pull up in action.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your advice. I also tried the lower frequency effect, but it didn't work. The reset pulse remained the same.
Technical support from STM also informed me that the pulse length cannot be influenced in any way by software.

I am closing this topic by saying that the only solution is hardware modification of the board. Thank you.